# Need help turning this JSON data into an array for MySQL

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, api, axios

This may have been answered somewhere but I couldnt fund anything related to my issue. I am trying to send API data of an album Titles by an artist to my MySQL database. This is what I have. I gdont understand how to get to send it into an array and deliver the information to the database. Any tips?

```
 const axios = require('axios');

var sql = require('./mysql.js');


// Connect to the database

sql.con.connect(function(err) { 
if (err) throw err;
console.log("Connected!");

})
```

```
//Make a call to the audio DB api using axios as a https call

 axios.get('https://www.theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/APIkey/searchalbum.php?s=the_weeknd')
 .then(result => {
 // Log raw data returned 
 console.log(result.data);
// Parse the data 
var data = JSON.parse(result.data); 

.then(result => {

// Log raw data returned
console.log(result.data);
// Parse the data
var data = JSON.parse(result.data);

//convert the JSON information into an array or loop through each album in the JSON and do a single inserte
//need to get information into an array 
//Insert the data into the database



sql.con.query('INSERT INTO AlbumTitle (album_name) VALUES?', [records], function (err, albumdata) {

if (err) throw err;

console.log(result.affectedRows + " record inserted"); 
});        

});



// Close the database connection

 sql.con.end(function(err){


 if (err) throw err;

 console.log("connection terminated");  

 });
```

Comment: *convert the JSON information into an array or loop through each album in the JSON and do a single insert* ??? What's the reason? If JSON is valid then provide it to MySQL as-is.

Comment: Youre probably right Its just when I run node on it I just get an error on the JSON.parse "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1" so I felt I was missing something then?

Comment: provide JSON content - maybe it is really invalid?

Comment: am I not providing content with the axios.get line with the link?

Comment: 1) I have no desire to click on the links I don't need. Especially when this link access needs authorization. 2) You must show strictly the value obtained - it is possible that it differs from one obtained by me due to some implicit convertions or different settings.